# smart art style diagram wih tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a question concerning drawing something similar to a smart art feature. If I have a diagram like so:

[image]

The first thing I can do is draw the individual panels:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[margin = 1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,calc,shapes,arrows,snakes,shapes.geometric,patterns}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[y = 13mm, x = 10mm,decoration = snake] % used for aspect ratio of diagram
\tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\scriptsize] % ensure all text is relatively small
\coordinate (clipping area) at (10, 5.9);% The figure is drawn a bit bigger, and then clipped:
\clip (0,0) rectangle (clipping area);

% Next reference points are relative to the lower left corner of the clipping area
\coordinate (water level) at (0, 6);
\coordinate (bottom)      at (5, 1);       % (bottom of the pit)
\coordinate (ground1)     at (0, 6);       % (left shore)
\coordinate (ground2)     at (10, 6);      % (right shore)
\coordinate (sedFlux)     at (5, 2.2);     % location where we need the sediment flux arrow

% Coordinates of the bigger area really drawn
\coordinate (lower left)  at ([xshift=-5mm, yshift=-5mm] 0,0);
\coordinate (upper right) at ([xshift=5mm,  yshift=5mm] clipping area);

% Draw the water and ripples
\draw [draw=blue!80!black, decoration={bumps, mirror, segment length=6mm}, decorate,
     bottom color=cyan!60!black, top color=blue!20!white] 
  (lower left) rectangle (water level-|upper right);

% Draw the ground
\draw [draw=white, fill=white] 
(lower left) -- (lower left|-ground1)  --
(ground1) .. controls ($(ground1)!.3!(bottom)$) and (bottom-|ground1) ..
(bottom) .. controls (bottom-|ground2) and ($(ground2)!.3!(bottom)$) .. 
(ground2) -- (ground2-|upper right) -- (lower left-|upper right) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is it then possible to use this diagram and others to draw something like a smart diagram where instead of having text you could gave separate diagrams? I would eventually like to end up with something like:

[image]

But obviously each of the panels will not be identical. Assuming that the panels are identical can anyone suggest a way of doing this?

Comment: You can start looking at: [create-diagrams-in-latex-with-tikz](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95044/create-diagrams-in-latex-with-tikz/95069#95069)

Comment: Great, so I can draw each individual diagram, what is the best way to now draw them in a smart art style?

Comment: A TikZ approach would be to use a `\matrix` where you can place arbitrary TikZ code in the cells. For a smarter layout, take a look at the [`smartdiagram`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/smartdiagram) package. If you always use the same picture it would be best to store it in a box (look up `\sbox` and `\usebox`) and then you can use it in the nodes. (Nesting TikZ pictures can be a nasty business.)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel what can go wrong with nested tikz pictures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how to use commands `\sbox` and `\usebox` suggested by Qrrbrbirlbel, but as you want to draw not identical diagrams you can easily draw them in different positions with `scopes` help.

Next code uses [JLDiaz answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95069/1952) converted into a command and afterthat draws it whithin several scopes. On each scope you can add some particular modifications.

It's not the best solution but I hope it helps you to find a better one.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,calc}

\newcommand{\mydiagram}{%
% % Define some reference points 
% The figure is drawn a bit bigger, and then clipped to the following dimensions:
\coordinate (clipping area) at (10, 7);
\clip (0,0) rectangle (clipping area);
% Next reference points are relative to the lower left corner of the clipping area
\coordinate (water level) at (0, 6);
\coordinate (bottom)      at (5, 1.3);     % (bottom of the pit)
\coordinate (ground1)     at (0, 5);       % (left shore)
\coordinate (ground2)     at (10, 5);      % (right shore)
% Coordinates of the bigger area really drawn
\coordinate (lower left)  at ([xshift=-5mm, yshift=-5mm] 0,0);
\coordinate (upper right) at ([xshift=5mm,  yshift=5mm] clipping area);
% Draw the water and ripples
\draw [draw=blue!80!black, decoration={bumps, mirror, segment length=6mm}, decorate,
     bottom color=cyan!60!black, top color=blue!20!white] 
  (lower left) rectangle (water level-|upper right);
% Draw the ground
\draw [draw=brown!30!black, fill=brown] 
  (lower left) -- (lower left|-ground1)  --
  (ground1) .. controls ($(ground1)!.3!(bottom)$) and (bottom-|ground1) ..
  (bottom) .. controls (bottom-|ground2) and ($(ground2)!.3!(bottom)$) .. 
  (ground2) -- (ground2-|upper right) -- (lower left-|upper right) -- cycle;
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[shift={(-5,4)}]
\mydiagram
\node at (3,5,3,5) {A};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[shift={(6,-3.5)}]
\mydiagram
\node at (3,5,3,5) {B};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[shift={(-5,-11)}]
\mydiagram
\node at (3,5,3,5) {C};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[shift={(-16,-3.5)}]
\mydiagram
\node at (3,5,3,5) {D};
\end{scope}
\draw[->,red, very thick] (6,7) to[out=-10,in=100]  (11,3);
\draw[->,red, very thick] (11,-4) to[out=-100,in=10]  (6,-8);
\draw[->,red, very thick] (-6,-8) to[out=170,in=-80]  (-11,-4);
\draw[->,red, very thick] (-11,3) to[out=80,in=190]  (-6,7);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]